# How to play chunk audio in C# with ContentPushStream?

Tags: c#, html, audio, stream, audio-player

I have a byte stream in the memory that belongs to a video file.

Note that, the byte stream does not represent the whole video file, it is rather a chunk of the video file in bytes that I have available at that moment.
I want to be able to play this chunk on a video player, or stream it if I can. But, I want to control the flow of the stream by myself since I receive the source of the video from different servers.

We have tried the below sample:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820146/HTTP-Partial-Content-In-ASP-NET-Web-API-Video

In my case, the first chunk of file download and played the audio. After the next chunk loaded, even though file is updated, it’s not updated in the player. It needs to merge the chunk and update the file in the player. Please find the code snippet here:

```
            int count = 0;
            long remainingBytes = end - start + 1;
            long position = start;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ReadStreamBufferSize];

            byte[] temp = new byte[ReadStreamBufferSize];

            inputStream.Position = start;
            int item = 1;
            do
            {
                try
                {

                    byte[] byteAry = new byte[ReadStreamBufferSize];
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("D:\\test\\pp" + item + ".wav")){
                        byteAry = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\test\\pp" + item + ".wav");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    temp = temp.Concat(byteAry).ToArray();                    
                    inputStream = new MemoryStream(temp);

                    if (remainingBytes > ReadStreamBufferSize)
                        count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, ReadStreamBufferSize);
                    else
                        count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)remainingBytes);
                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(error);

                    break;
                }
                position = inputStream.Position + 100;
                end = inputStream.Length;
                remainingBytes = end - position + 1;
                item++;
            } while (position <= end);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to recreate the WAVE file header taking into account the size of all files and then append the audio data, something like the following:

```
int item = 1;

var inputWaveFiles = new List<WaveFile>();

while (File.Exists($@"D:\test\pp{item}.wav"))
{
    var waveFile = WaveFile.ReadWaveFile($@"D:\test\pp{item}.wav");
    inputWaveFiles.Add(waveFile);
    item++;
}

WaveFile.Merge(inputWaveFiles, @"D:\test\output.wav");

public class WaveFile
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public short Channels { get; set; }
    public int SampleRate { get; set; }
    public int DataLength { get; set; }
    public short BitsPerSample { get; set; }

    private void WriteHeader(string filename)
    {
        using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
            {
                file.Position = 0;
                writer.Write(new char[4] { 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F' });

                writer.Write(Length);

                writer.Write(new char[8] { 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E', 'f', 'm', 't', ' ' });

                writer.Write((int)16);

                writer.Write((short)1);
                writer.Write(Channels);

                writer.Write(SampleRate);

                writer.Write((int)(SampleRate * ((BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8)));

                writer.Write((short)((BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8));

                writer.Write(BitsPerSample);

                writer.Write(new char[4] { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a' });
                writer.Write(DataLength);
            }
        }
    }

    public static WaveFile ReadWaveFile(string filename)
    {
        var waveFile = new WaveFile();
        waveFile.Path = filename;

        using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file))
            {
                waveFile.Length = (int)file.Length - 8;
                file.Position = 22;
                waveFile.Channels = reader.ReadInt16();
                file.Position = 24;
                waveFile.SampleRate = reader.ReadInt32();
                file.Position = 34;
                waveFile.BitsPerSample = reader.ReadInt16();
                waveFile.DataLength = (int)file.Length - 44;
            }
        }
        return waveFile;
    }

    public static void Merge(List<WaveFile> waveFiles, string outputFilename)
    {
        var outputWave = new WaveFile();

        foreach(var waveFile in waveFiles)
        {
            outputWave.DataLength += waveFile.DataLength;
            outputWave.Length += waveFile.Length;
        }

        // Generate file with header (I just copy the sample rate etc.. from the first sound file)
        outputWave.BitsPerSample = waveFiles[0].BitsPerSample;
        outputWave.Channels = waveFiles[0].Channels;
        outputWave.SampleRate = waveFiles[0].SampleRate;
        outputWave.WriteHeader(outputFilename);

        // Append data
        foreach (var waveFile in waveFiles)
        {
            // Read wave file
            using (var fileReader = new FileStream(waveFile.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var inputData = new byte[fileReader.Length - 44];
                fileReader.Position = 44;
                fileReader.Read(inputData, 0, inputData.Length);

                // Write wave file
                using (var fileWriter = new FileStream(outputFilename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fileWriter))
                    {
                        writer.Write(inputData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**References**

http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15187/Concatenating-Wave-Files-Using-C-2005